# Thymeleaf 3 - multiple ternary evaluations possible?

Tags: thymeleaf

Does Thymeleaf 3 support multiple ternary conditions, such as:

```
cond1 ? do1 : cond2 ? do2 : do3
```

The following code works in Thymeleaf 3:

```
<th:block th:replace="${toolbar == true} ? ~{common/fragments :: _$pageToolbar} :  ~{app/fragments :: ${toolbar}}">
```

Where I'm passing `true`to get the default toolbar or a `string` to get a custom toolbar.

But this code, which should essentially remove the block if nothing is passed in the `toolbar` parameter generates a parsing exception:

```
<th:block th:replace="${toolbar == true} ? ~{common/fragments :: _$pageToolbar} : ${toolbar != null} ? ~{app/fragments :: ${toolbar}} : ~{common/fragments :: _$empty}">
```

Maybe I'm taking the wrong approach here?

The Thymeleaf parsing exception:

```
Caused by: org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateProcessingException: Could not parse as expression: "${toolbar == true} ? ~{common/fragments :: _$pageToolbar} : ${toolbar != null} ? ~{app/fragments :: ${toolbar}} : ~{common/fragments :: _$empty}" (template: "common/fragments" - line 70, col 15)
at org.thymeleaf.standard.expression.StandardExpressionParser.parseExpression(StandardExpressionParser.java:131) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar:3.0.6.RELEASE]
at org.thymeleaf.standard.expression.StandardExpressionParser.parseExpression(StandardExpressionParser.java:62) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar:3.0.6.RELEASE]
at org.thymeleaf.standard.expression.StandardExpressionParser.parseExpression(StandardExpressionParser.java:44) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar:3.0.6.RELEASE]
at org.thymeleaf.standard.processor.AbstractStandardFragmentInsertionTagProcessor.computeFragment(AbstractStandardFragmentInsertionTagProcessor.java:387) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar:3.0.6.RELEASE]
at org.thymeleaf.standard.processor.AbstractStandardFragmentInsertionTagProcessor.doProcess(AbstractStandardFragmentInsertionTagProcessor.java:111) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar:3.0.6.RELEASE]
at org.thymeleaf.processor.element.AbstractAttributeTagProcessor.doProcess(AbstractAttributeTagProcessor.java:74) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar:3.0.6.RELEASE]
at org.thymeleaf.processor.element.AbstractElementTagProcessor.process(AbstractElementTagProcessor.java:95) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar:3.0.6.RELEASE]
at org.thymeleaf.util.ProcessorConfigurationUtils$ElementTagProcessorWrapper.process(ProcessorConfigurationUtils.java:633) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar:3.0.6.RELEASE]
at org.thymeleaf.engine.ProcessorTemplateHandler.handleOpenElement(ProcessorTemplateHandler.java:1314) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar:3.0.6.RELEASE]
at org.thymeleaf.engine.OpenElementTag.beHandled(OpenElementTag.java:205) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar:3.0.6.RELEASE]
at org.thymeleaf.engine.Model.process(Model.java:282) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar:3.0.6.RELEASE]
at org.thymeleaf.engine.ProcessorTemplateHandler.handleOpenElement(ProcessorTemplateHandler.java:1587) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar:3.0.6.RELEASE]
at org.thymeleaf.engine.TemplateHandlerAdapterMarkupHandler.handleOpenElementEnd(TemplateHandlerAdapterMarkupHandler.java:304) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar:3.0.6.RELEASE]
at org.thymeleaf.templateparser.markup.InlinedOutputExpressionMarkupHandler$InlineMarkupAdapterPreProcessorHandler.handleOpenElementEnd(InlinedOutputExpressionMarkupHandler.java:278) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar:3.0.6.RELEASE]
at org.thymeleaf.standard.inline.OutputExpressionInlinePreProcessorHandler.handleOpenElementEnd(OutputExpressionInlinePreProcessorHandler.java:186) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar:3.0.6.RELEASE]
at org.thymeleaf.templateparser.markup.InlinedOutputExpressionMarkupHandler.handleOpenElementEnd(InlinedOutputExpressionMarkupHandler.java:124) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar:3.0.6.RELEASE]
at org.attoparser.HtmlElement.handleOpenElementEnd(HtmlElement.java:109) ~[attoparser-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar:2.0.4.RELEASE]
at org.attoparser.HtmlMarkupHandler.handleOpenElementEnd(HtmlMarkupHandler.java:297) ~[attoparser-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar:2.0.4.RELEASE]
at org.attoparser.MarkupEventProcessorHandler.handleOpenElementEnd(MarkupEventProcessorHandler.java:402) ~[attoparser-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar:2.0.4.RELEASE]
at org.attoparser.ParsingElementMarkupUtil.parseOpenElement(ParsingElementMarkupUtil.java:159) ~[attoparser-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar:2.0.4.RELEASE]
at org.attoparser.MarkupParser.parseBuffer(MarkupParser.java:710) ~[attoparser-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar:2.0.4.RELEASE]
at org.attoparser.MarkupParser.parseDocument(MarkupParser.java:301) ~[attoparser-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar:2.0.4.RELEASE]
... 79 common frames omitted
```

Comment: Yeah, you can do that just fine... what is `~{common/fragment :: _$empty}` supposed to mean?  I've never seen `_$empty` as an expression.

Comment: it's just the name of a fragment.

Comment: @Metroids Just in case, I tried renaming the fragments to remove the `_$`, but I still get the same parsing error.  Any ideas on what's causing the error?

Comment: @rayduels I'm confused, what is the type of `toolbar`? Is it string, isn't it? I'm asking because you use it like it was either a boolean (`${toolbar == true}`) or a string (`~{app/fragments :: ${toolbar}}`). Wouldn't be less confusing to enclose `true` from first condition with single quotes (`${toolbar == 'true'}`)?

Comment: It's a common design pattern I've used in other languages...toolbar is polymorphic.  Using boolean (true) is just a way of getting the default toolbar, without having to know it's underlying fragment name.

Comment: Aah, now I see.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> Does Thymeleaf 3 support multiple ternary conditions, such as:
>
> `cond1 ? do1 : cond2 ? do2 : do3`

Yes, it does. Just enclose the second ternary operator with brackets to get rid of parse exception.

`cond1 ? do1 : (cond2 ? do2 : do3)`

Your expression should work after applying that.

Comment: That worked perfectly!  It's strange that you have to include the parens. In fact, it turns out that you have to include them for each 'else' portion of the statement, for example: `cond1 ? do1 : (cond2 ? do2 : (cond3 ? do3 : do4))`.  It would be useful for the Thymeleaf folks to update their parser to work without having to group the statements with parens.